# how to use the function ANOVA to multiple models saved in a list?

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, anova

I have a list that contains multiple linear regression models like this:

```
> list
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = formula, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           V1  
  512.91937     -0.04731  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = formula, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           V2  
  499.34648     -0.01863  


[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = formula, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           V3  
   504.0089      -0.0271
```

The function `ANOVA`is mostly used to choose the best model, so it allows `n` models to compare it. That is:

```
anova(model1,model2,model3,...,modeln)
```

So what I want to do is something similar. When you have three models, there is no problem, but I have a list of 100 models and they can be more. So I need to save this step manually. I need something like

```
anova(list[[1]],list[[2]],...,list[[n]])
```

May be useful functions of the `apply` family, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `do.call`

```
> l <- replicate(10, lm(rnorm(10) ~ 1), simplify = FALSE) 
> do.call(anova, l)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model  1: rnorm(10) ~ 1
Model  2: rnorm(10) ~ 1
Model  3: rnorm(10) ~ 1
Model  4: rnorm(10) ~ 1
Model  5: rnorm(10) ~ 1
Model  6: rnorm(10) ~ 1
Model  7: rnorm(10) ~ 1
Model  8: rnorm(10) ~ 1
Model  9: rnorm(10) ~ 1
Model 10: rnorm(10) ~ 1
   Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq F Pr(>F)
1       9 12.8275                      
2       9  5.6966  0    7.1309         
3       9 11.3766  0   -5.6801         
4       9 12.2143  0   -0.8376         
5       9  6.1445  0    6.0697         
6       9 14.0516  0   -7.9071         
7       9  6.5769  0    7.4748         
8       9  8.5335  0   -1.9566         
9       9  4.4292  0    4.1042         
10      9  9.0037  0   -4.5745
```

Though, are you sure you want to do that with what seems to be no-nested models? Further, you should avoid defining object that coincides with `base` functions like `list`.

Comment: Also note, that the list needs to be unnamed to work for some reason.